# Динамическая загрузка элементов в QScrollArea

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qscrollarea

Работаю с *PyQt5*. Есть `QScrollArea`, в котором есть несколько `horizontalLayout`. 
В этих `horizontalLayout` есть свои кнопки и поля.

В этом `scrollview` статично **`10`** `horizontalLayout`.

Как можно реализовать такой функционал: я например в поле соседнем ввожу цифру **`5`** и нажимаю кнопку, а затем в `scrollview` появится **`5`** `horizontalLayout` с контентом, а не **`10`**.

Прикрепил фото Этого `scrollview`, в котором изначально **`10`** `horizontalLayout`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я рекомендую вам не изобретать колесо, а воспользоваться QListWidget и, кроме всего прочего, его метод QItemWidget doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#setItemWidget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Widget(QGroupBox):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()
        self.setTitle(name.upper())        
        self.name = name

        self.lbl = QLabel(f'Label {self.name}')
        self.lbl.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.TextSelectableByMouse)

        self.btn = QPushButton(f'Button {self.name}')
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.printsignal)
        
        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(f'LineEdit {self.name}')

        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lbl, 0, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn, 0, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)

    def printsignal(self):
        print(
            f"clicked: \n\tTitle --> {self.title()}"
            f" \n\tLabel --> {self.lbl.text()}"
            f" \n\tLineEdit --> {self.lineEdit.text()}"
        )


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        self.tlist = [
            'thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3', 'thing4', 'thing5',
            'thing6', 'thing7', 'thing8', 'thing9', 'thing10',
        ]

        self.controls = QWidget()
        self.controlsLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.controls)

        self.widgets = []
        for name in self.tlist:
            item = Widget(name)
            self.controlsLayout.addWidget(item)
            self.widgets.append(item)

        spacer = QSpacerItem(1, 1, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.controlsLayout.addItem(spacer)

        self.scroll = QScrollArea()
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.controls)
 
        self.spinBox = QSpinBox()
        self.spinBox.setRange(1, 10)
        self.spinBox.setProperty("value", 10)
        self.spinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.update_display)        

        containerLayout = QVBoxLayout(centralWidget)
        containerLayout.addWidget(self.spinBox)
        containerLayout.addWidget(self.scroll)

    def update_display(self, value):
        for i, widget in enumerate(self.widgets):
            if i+1 <= value:
                widget.show()
            else:
                widget.hide()

    def sizeHint(self):
        return self.scroll.widget().size() * 0.7
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]